# How to show ColorPicker from my action in IntelliJ IDEA plugin DevKit?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, plugins, intellij-plugin

How to show ColorPicker from my action in IntelliJ IDEA plugin DevKit?
For example I have an action:

```
public class TextBoxes extends AnAction {
    public void actionPerformed(AnActionEvent event) {
        // Some code
    }
}
```

In which I want to display ColorPicker widget:

```
ColorPicker colorPicker = new ColorPicker(args); // Like that
ColorPicker.showDialog(args); // Or like that
```

In new ColorPicker(args) format there is a Disposable parent object required. Where should I get this one?
In ColorPicker.showDialog(args); there is also a Component parent object required. And again I can't understand where should I get this object? 
And which one is the right way to display ColorPicker from com.intellij.ui.ColorPicker package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please do it like this:

```
public class TextBoxes extends AnAction {
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(AnActionEvent event) {
    Color color = ColorPicker.showDialog(...)
  }
}
```